# EF Core: Can I map nullable SQL type to non-nullable value type in my Entity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a SQL VIEW that maps to following entity:

```
public class MyView {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

I use it like `dbContext.MyView.ToArrayAsync()` or `dbContext.MyView.Where(e => e.Count > 0)`, etc.

The view returns NULL in Count columns in production and I'm getting NullReferenceExeption when evaluating the queries.

**Can I configure the mapping so that NULL values will be mapped to `default(int)` resp `0`?**

I have tried to use nullable backing field `private int? _count`, but still getting exception. The requirement is, that I don't want to change SQL view or the my code except the entity itself or the mapping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping NULLs to type default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362908/mapping-nulls-to-type-default)

Comment: @MindSwipe: No, because it breaks queries that uses that column, e.g. `dbContext.MyView.Where(e => e.Count > 0)`. I can't use Ignored property in queries. Besides, it does not answer the question. It's a workaround using different technique, but not an answer

Comment: Please, take the close votes back, it was premature ;)

Comment: You've tried using a nullable backing *field*, but AFAIK EF only maps to *properties*. Also, I fail to see how the backing field would break the query in any other way than mapping null to `default(int)` would

Comment: I have used [HasField("_count")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations#field-and-property-access) - so EF does map to fields :)  But I have also tried to use "baking property" workaround you posted. It suggest to ignore the original property. Once you ignore it, you cant use it query expressions, because EF Core does not now how to translate it (in WHERE condition for example). Ignored property cannot be translated to SQL

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a error handling issue rather then mapping issue.
There are a couple of ways I see to handle this:

1. is to use [expression bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) to set `int` to 0 - I don't see it as the best option in your case because again, the problem relates to error handling.
2. My recommendation is to use [`FirstOrDefualt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0) or `.ToList()`. It will return null / count of 0 if no records were found, this way you will be able to query accordingly.

I.E.:

```
var record = dbContext.MyView.Where(e => e.Count > 0).FirstOrDefault();
var found = record != null ? record : 0;
```

Or:

```
var records = dbContext.MyView.Where(e => e.Count > 0).ToList();
var found = records.Count() > 0 ? records : new List<T>();
```

This will provide you with a readable way to handle null error. Then if you passed the check, you can bring the rest of your data.